# Ruby Capybara Having more than 1 scenario within a cucumber feature undefined method `go_to_my_own_profile_page' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara

I have a cucumber feature that I want to split it in multiple scenarios
when I run the tests failed with

`` undefined method `go_to_my_own_profile_page' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
      ./features/step_definitions/register_actions_steps.rb:51:in `/^I click on user profile icon $/'
      features/com.company/1register.feature:22:in `Given I click on user profile icon ' ``

If I keep only one scenario within a feature works fine.

My feature file with only one scenario:

```
use capybara 
Capybara::DSL

@register
Feature: Register with email

Scenario: Test1
Given I click on user profile icon
```

As a project structure I try to keep the object pattern.

My Gemfile:

```
source "http://rubygems.org"
gem "cucumber"
gem "capybara", "1.1.4", :group => :test
gem "selenium-webdriver"
gem 'capybara-screenshot', :group => :test
gem 'rspec-rails'
gem 'minitest', '< 5'
gem 'capybara_minitest_spec'
gem 'capybara-webkit'
```

Cucumber configuration:

```
# config/cucumber.yml
##YAML Template
---
default:  --profile bvt --tags @register,register1,@account_settings,@link_fb_to_sl,@link_tw_to_sl
html_report: --format progress --format html --out=./results/html_reports/features_report.html
bvt: --tags @register,@account_settings,@link_fb_to_sl,@link_tw_to_sl
register: --tags @register
account: --tags @account_settings
twitter: --tags @register_twitter
lobbing: --tags @lobbing
facebook: --tags @link_fb_to_sl
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Without enough info, I can only guess that there is an error in a step definitions file that causes the go_to_my_own_profile_page method to be undefined. (1) please post your working feature file - with one scenario - and your feature file after the change - with two scenarios (2) please post the code in features/step_definitions/register_actions_steps.rb around line 51 (3) also check that my edits labelled your code and data correctly

Comment: If you have found the answer to your question, help others and post it below. If not, please post the extra info I suggested.